# How can pass value from model to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `foreach` in the razor :

```
  <ul>
        @foreach (var node in Model)
        {
            var par = node.Id;
            <li onclick="GetSubMenu(@node.Id)" id="@node.Id">
                @node.Title
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

in onclick i called method in the :

```
  function GetSubMenu(parentId) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/Menu/GetSubMenu",
        data: { pageNumber: parentId },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

    }).done(function (result) {

    });
}
```

but when i click on `<li>` the `GetSubMenu` does not fire , what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using data attribute.

```
  <ul>
        @foreach (var node in Model)
        {
            <li id="nodeID_"+@node.Id data-nodeid=@node.Id onclick="GetSubMenu(this)" >
                @node.Title
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

and get data in javascript.

```
function GetSubMenu(e) {
    var parentId = obj.getAttribute('data-nodeid');
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/Menu/GetSubMenu",
        data: { pageNumber: parentId },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

    }).done(function (result) {

    });
}
```

you can also use dataset

```
function GetSubMenu(e) {
        var parentId = e.dataset.nodeid;
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/Menu/GetSubMenu",
            data: { pageNumber: parentId },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

        }).done(function (result) {

        });
    }
```